# Merge two CSV files and return output as dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please I need help merging two CSV files into one dictionary.

Dataset
*student*
**name,  matricNo, dob,address,department**

1. Margaret Chase, 201001,1976-12-02,USCGC Walker FPO AP 28772, Micro Biology
2. Erica Woods,201002,2010-02-03,"565 Patricia Coves Apt. 659 Lake Brandiside, MS 61181",French

**Records**

**title,unit,code,score,term,session,student_id**

1. English,2,ENG101,60,Fall,2020,201001
2. Chemistry I,4,CHE101,70,Fall,2021,201001
3. Chemistry I,4,CHE101,61,Fall,2021,201002
4. Maths,3,MTH101,52,Spring,2020,201002
5. English,2,ENG101,80,Fall,2020,201003
6. Chemistry I,4,CHE101,56,Fall,2021,201003
7. Geology I,4,Geo101,56,Fall,2021,201003

[image]

[image]

I have tried reading the two csv into separate data frames
[image]

Trying to merge the two df  looks ok but converting the df into dictionary is not giving desired result.

[image]

What am getting when I try to convert the df to dictionary
[image]

Expected output

```
student_records = {
      "name": "James Webb",
      "id": "201003",
      "courses":[
         {"title": "English", "unit": 2, "code": "ENG101", "score": 60, "term": "Fall", "session":'2020'},
         {"title": "Chemistry I", "unit": 4, "code": "CHE101", "score": 70, "term": "Fall", "session":'2021'},
         {"title": "Maths", "unit": 3, "code": "MTH101", "score": 80, "term": "Spring", "session":'2020'},
         {"title": "Chemistry II", "unit": 4, "code": "CHE102", "score": 91, "term": "Spring", "session":'2021'}, 
         {"title": "History", "unit": 2, "code": "HIS102", "score": 40, "term": "Spring", "session":'2020'}
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to_json() ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably skip pandas and just use the csv module.  Conceptually we will read in students into a dictionary based on the key of student id to make lookups easier,  Then we will read in classes and find the corresponding student to append the class to. Finally, we can take the values of our lookup as a list:

```py
import csv

with open("students.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as students_in:
    merged = {
        student["matricNo"] : student 
        for student
        in csv.DictReader(students_in, skipinitialspace=True)
    }

with open("classes.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as classes_in:
    for student_class in csv.DictReader(classes_in):
        student_id = student_class["student_id"]
        if student_id not in merged:
            print(f"student not found: {student_id}")
            continue
        merged[student_id].setdefault("classes", []).append(student_class)

merged = list(merged.values())

print(merged)
```

Giving us:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Margaret Chase",
        "matricNo": "201001",
        "dob": "1976-12-02",
        "address": "USCGC Walker FPO AP 28772",
        "department": "Micro Biology",
        "classes": [
            {
                "title": "English",
                "unit": "2",
                "code": "ENG101",
                "score": "60",
                "term": "Fall",
                "session": "2020",
                "student_id": "201001"
            },
            {
                "title": "Chemistry I",
                "unit": "4",
                "code": "CHE101",
                "score": "70",
                "term": "Fall",
                "session": "2021",
                "student_id": "201001"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Erica Woods",
        "matricNo": "201002",
        "dob": "2010-02-03",
        "address": "565 Patricia Coves Apt. 659 Lake Brandiside, MS 61181",
        "department": "French",
        "classes": [
            {
                "title": "Chemistry I",
                "unit": "4",
                "code": "CHE101",
                "score": "61",
                "term": "Fall",
                "session": "2021",
                "student_id": "201002"
            },
            {
                "title": "Maths",
                "unit": "3",
                "code": "MTH101",
                "score": "52",
                "term": "Spring",
                "session": "2020",
                "student_id": "201002"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Many thanks this is exactly what am looking for. Appreciate!!!